# How to force change password windows server when logon with config file on openstack

Tags: cloud, openstack, windows-server

I have created image windows server 2012R2 and 2016 and used it on openstack then I want to force user change password like "User must change password next logon" by config file and I found 2 scripts for using, first,

> ## ps1
>
> net user $username $password

for setting username and password and second,

> Set-Aduser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true

for force changing password. I fill 2 parts on the same config file but they are not work together, when I fill password which is $password then windows will show desktop but if I fill old password then windows show massage "You must change password before" I want it works like this... when I fill $password then it shows "You must change password before"

Hope you understood me, because I'm Thai, my English not well.

Thank you for helping me.

> ## ps1
>
> net user Administrator Frame789
>
> Set-Aduser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true

Answer (score 0):

Everyone, now I found solution for fixing this problem by myself.

I just use /logonpasswordchg:yes stand at the back like this

> ## ps1
>
> net user Administrator Frame789 /logonpasswordchg:yes

I hope this work for you too.

ps. It doesn't work with windows XP.